# How to auto scale docker containers in a regular cloud server?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, rackspace

To make a scale-able architecture with docker containers is a very attractive solutions to deal with scale-ability issue. We can auto scale docker containers in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk environment or in a vendor specific pass environments.

What is the best way to make your own scale-able docker architecture on commodity cloud servers such as Digital Ocean or Rackspace that will auto provisions containers based on loads.

Comment: This seems overly broad. There is no "best" way to make a scalable Docker architecture. There are solutions out there. You should review them and see what fits best for your scenario. Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do on this nefarious "scalable Docker architecture running on commodity cloud servers"?

Comment: Lets say, I have a worker container which connect to job queue and do the processing. Now based on the load, it may scale to multiple container on the same digital ocean droplet, but also can provision new digital ocean droplets and scale up and down. It may be on other cloud environment too like Rackspace. I'm not sure it may need to call Digital ocean API to provision new droplets for scaling. @AndyShinn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most known solution for managing scaling a docker-based infrastructure are:

- [docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/)
- [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/)
- for CoreOS, [Fleet](https://coreos.com/fleet/)
- [Apache Mesos](https://mesos.apache.org/)

[This article](http://radar.oreilly.com/2015/10/swarm-v-fleet-v-kubernetes-v-mesos.html) mentions:

> In terms of scale, only Mesos has been proven to support large-scale systems of hundreds or thousands of nodes. However, when looking at small clusters of, say, less than a dozen nodes, Mesos may be an overly complex solution.

As [mentioned here](http://technologyconversations.com/2015/11/04/docker-clustering-tools-compared-kubernetes-vs-docker-swarm/):

> Almost everything we can do with Docker we can do with Swarm as well only on a much larger scale. There’s nothing new to do, no configurations to be duplicated and nothing new to learn.

[image: https://i2.wp.com/blog.docker.com/media/2015/11/image00.png?w=1887]

So start with Docker Swarm first, and if particular needs arise, look for the other solutions.

See:

- "[Deploy and Manage Any Cluster Manager with Docker Swarm](https://blog.docker.com/2015/11/deploy-manage-cluster-docker-swarm/)"
- "[Using Machine to provision Docker Swarm clusters](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started-cloud/)"

Comment: A quick question, can docker swarm provision new server or only work in one machine with multiple containers?